# rsExecutionNotFound when directly accessing an SSRS report

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I have an SSRS report that can I access from the Web Portal but once I try to access it directly through the URL, I get the following error: `Execution 'xxx' cannot be found (rsExecutionNotFound)`.

I looked at the logs on the Report Server and the error there says  `userName: mydomain\myusername not found in the database`.

But, of course, it is in the database - I can access the report from the Web Portal.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** The same link now works, two days later.

Comment: If the same link works two days later, does that mean it's no longer an issue?

Comment: No, it means its an intermittent issue.  Another report is experiencing the same behavior now.

Comment: @JHFB [this link](http://theruntime.com/blogs/thomasswilliams/archive/2009/07/24/reporting-services-execution-xxx-cannot-be-found.aspx) seems to describe the same sort of behavior that you are experiencing.

Comment: @JHFB also, it seems that there could also be a timeout issue. check the activity of the server when you get the error and when you don't get the error. i recommend sp_WhoIsActive

Answer (score 1):

What I have seen in a case like you ask about is you hit a report, and copy the url out and then try to hit it later. Reports have session state, especially if you change paramaters,etc. The url will look like a report url with some funky querystring data added to the end. You can't share that because SSRS can't take your "session state" and then find it later.

Answer (score 0):

@zlatan mentions timeout in the context of the SQL performance but we found that in our case we got the error because of user session timeout in Reporting Services. There is an explanation as well as a script to change the timeouts on [John Gallardo's web log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgalla/session-timeout-during-execution)

In case that page is missing, create an .rss file with this content:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim props() as [Property]
    props = new [Property] () { new [Property](), new [Property]() }
    
    props(0).Name = "SessionTimeout"
    props(0).Value = timeout
    
    props(1).Name = "SessionAccessTimeout"
    props(1).Value = timeout
    
    rs.SetSystemProperties(props)
End Sub
```

Then call it with rs.exe like this:

```
rs -i sessionTimeout.rss -s http://localhost/reportserver -v timeout="6000"
```